# Vectorized calculation of adjacency matrix

Tags: r, parallel-processing, signal-processing, graph-theory

I have the following function:

```
CFC_GLM <- function(data, frequency_bins){
    adj_mat <- matrix(0, nrow = dim(data)[1], ncol = dim(data)[1])
    bf_filters <- list()
    combs <- combinations(length(frequency_bins), 2, repeats.allowed = T)
    all_adj_mat <- list()

for(z in 1:length(frequency_bins)){
bf_filters[[z]] <- butter(3, c(frequency_bins[[z]][1]/1200, 
frequency_bins[[z]][2]/1200), type = "pass")
}

for(f in 1:nrow(combs)){
  for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
    for(j in 1:dim(data)[1]){
  
      sensor_1 <- data[i,]
      sensor_2 <- data[j,]

      sensor_1_filt = filtfilt(bf_filters[[combs[f,1]]], sensor_1)
      sensor_2_filt = filtfilt(bf_filters[[combs[f,2]]], sensor_2)

      a_y <- abs(hilbert(sensor_2_filt, 1200))
      a_x <- abs(hilbert(sensor_1_filt, 1200))
      theta_x <- angle(hilbert(sensor_1_filt, 1200)) %% 2*pi

      a_x_norm <- (a_x - mean(a_x))/std(a_x)
      a_y_norm <- (a_y - mean(a_y))/std(a_y)
      theta_x_norm <- (theta_x - mean(theta_x))/std(theta_x)
  
      fit <- lm(a_y_norm ~ sin(theta_x_norm) + cos(theta_x_norm) + 
      a_x_norm)
      summ <- summary(fit)
      r <- sqrt(summ$r.squared)
  
      adj_mat[i,j] <- r
    }
  }
  all_adj_mat[[f]] <- adj_mat
}
return(all_adj_mat)
}
```

Just to summarize, the function takes a matrix of signals (246 sensors by 2400 samples), performs some signal processing, and then performs a GLM between every possible pairs of sensors. This process is repeated for 4 frequency bandwidths and their combinations (within and cross-frequency coupling). Right now, this code seems terribly inefficient and takes a really long time to run. Is there a way to vectorize/parallelize this function? I have researched this question extensively and cannot seem to find an answer.

I am not sure whether to make some of the tasks within the function parallel or just make the whole function able to be called by parApply (vectorized). My intuition is the latter but I am not sure how to approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

## Reproducible Example

```
test_data <- c(-347627.104358097, 821947.421444641, 496824.676355433, 
-178091.364312102, -358842.250713998, 234666.210462063, 
-1274153.04141668, 
1017066.42839987, -158388.137875357, 191691.279588641, 
-16231.2106151229, 
378249.600546794, 1080850.88212858, -688841.640871254, 
-616713.991288002, 
639401.465180969, -1625802.44142751, 472370.867686569, 
-631863.239075449, 
-598755.248911174, 276422.966753179, -44010.9403226763, 
1569374.08537143, 
-1138797.2585617, -824232.849278583, 955783.332556046, 
-1943384.98409094, 
-54443.829280377, -1040354.44654998, -1207674.05255178, 
496481.331429747, 
-417435.356472725, 1886817.1254085, -1477199.59091112, 
-947353.716505171, 
1116336.49812969, -2173805.84111182, -574875.152250742, 
-1343996.2219146, 
-1492260.06197604, 626856.67540728, -713761.48191904, 1987730.27341334, 
-1673384.77863935, -968522.886481198, 1089458.71433614, 
-2274932.19262517, 
-1096749.79392427, -1520842.86946059, -1390794.61065106, 
669864.477272507, 
-906096.822125892, 1863506.59188299, -1720956.06310511, 
-889359.420058576, 
885300.628410276, -2224340.54992297, -1619386.88041896, 
-1570131.07127786, 
-934848.556063722, 644671.113108699, -973418.329437102, 
1541962.53750178, 
-1636863.31666018, -728992.972371437, 551297.997356909, 
-2026413.5471505, 
-2129730.49230266, -1511423.25789691, -236962.889589694, 
580683.399845852, 
-906261.700784793, 1080101.95011954, -1455931.89179814, 
-518630.187846405, 
158846.288141661, -1715610.22092989, -2601349.5081924, 
-1380068.64260811, 
541310.557194977, 509125.333244057, -711696.682554995, 
551748.792106809, 
-1222430.29467688, -293847.487823853, -215078.751157158, 
-1354005.89576504, 
-2997647.23289805, -1220136.14918605, 1231169.98678596, 
455388.081391798, 
-415489.975542684, 32724.7895795912, -980848.930757441, 
-86618.5594163355, 
-506333.915891838, -1022235.58829567, -3279232.01820961, 
-1076344.95091665, 
1696655.88400158), .Dim = c(10L, 10L))

frequency_bins <- list(band1 = c(2,4), band2 = c(4,12), band3 = 
c(12,30), band4 = c(30,100))

system.time(test_result <- CFC_GLM(test_data, frequency_bins))
user  system elapsed 
1.839   0.009   1.849
```

I'm not sure how to include the result in a manageable way. Sorry for the naivety. This is only with 10 sensors by 10 samples, to have a manageable test set.

Comment: Vectorizing would likely be better than parallelising in this case. Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: That was my suspicion but I am not sure how to go about it. I have added an example. Let me know if there is anything else I could provide. Thanks

Comment: I'm working through my code again with the test data you posted. There are definitely some bugs in my code. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate your effort. There were only some minor bugs in terms of indexing and such. The main thing I couldn't figure out was why it was taking the same amount of time and why I couldn't just use parApply instead of apply.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat I would suggest predeclaring the length of your lists.

```
bf_filters <- rep(list(NA), length(frequency_bins))
all_adj_mat <- rep(list(NA), nrow(combos))

#this is your function to be applied
i_j_fun <- function ( perms ) {
        sensor_1_filt = filtfilt(bf_filters[[combos[f,1]]], data[perms[1],])
        sensor_2_filt = filtfilt(bf_filters[[combos[f,2]]], data[persm[2],])
        a_y <- abs(hilbert(sensor_2_filt, 1200))
        a_x <- abs(hilbert(sensor_1_filt, 1200))
        theta_x <- angle(hilbert(sensor_1_filt, 1200)) %% 2*pi

        a_x_norm <- (a_x - mean(a_x))/std(a_x)
        a_y_norm <- (a_y - mean(a_y))/std(a_y)
        theta_x_norm <- (theta_x - mean(theta_x))/std(theta_x)

        fit <- lm(a_y_norm ~ sin(theta_x_norm) + cos(theta_x_norm) + 
                  a_x_norm)
        summ <- summary(fit)
        r <- sqrt(summ$r.squared)

        return(r)
    }
```

Your `i` and `j` for loops can be turned into a function and used with apply.

```
#perms acts like the for loop 
perms <- permuations(dim(data)[1], 2, seq_len(dim(data)[1]))
for(f in 1:nrow(combs)){
    all_adj_mat[[f]] <- matrix(apply(perms, 1, i_j_fun), 
    nrow = dim(data)[1], ncol = dim(data[2]), byrow = TRUE)
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: This code seems to reproduce the results but doesn't seem to have any significant time gains over the nested for loops. Also, when I try to make it parallel, it doesn't seem to be using sockets (I am on a Mac) so there are errors in accessing the variables (including those in the final for loop). So even if I specify the global variables and packages in the cluster nodes, I get the error that there is no variable "f". Hopefully that makes sense.